# Bucle infinito con dos eventos <Configure> - Tkinter - Python

Tags: python, tkinter, eventos, font-size

Tengo dos widgets que estan enlazados al mismo evento:

- Un frame que hace que se ajuste la imagen a la pantalla
- Un Label que quiero que se ajuste la fuente a la pantalla

El problema es que al añadir el segundo widget se hace un bucle infinito y es como que el evento generado empieza a aumentar el valor 'height' de la pantalla.

El frame es:

```
class FrameImgResizable(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master, image=None, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

    if not image:
        self.image = Image.open(image_labelFrameUser_Big)
    else:
        self.image = Image.open(image)
    self.img_copy = self.image.copy()

    self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

    self.background = tk.Label(self, image=self.background_image)
    self.background.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
    self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

def _resize_image(self, event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height

    self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

    self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
    self.background.configure(image=self.background_image)
```

y el widget label es:

```
    self.frame_btn = tk.Frame(self.frame_perfil, bg=bg_labels_white, cursor="hand2")
    self.frame_btn.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.frame_btn.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
    self.frame_btn.place(relwidth=0.98, relheight=0.07, relx=0.01, rely=0.48)

    self.btn_tweets = tk.Label(self.frame_btn, text="Tweets", cursor="hand2",
                               font=self.font_title, justify='center')
    self.btn_tweets.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.btn_tweets.bind('<Configure>', self.resize_font)

def resize_font(self, event):
    self.font_title.configure(size=(int(event.height * 0.8)))
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué se genera un bucle infinito haciendo que le valor de 'height' aumente? y, ¿cómo hago para genera ese mismo evento para ambas cosas sin que pete de esta manera?

Gracias de antemano